# Possible to replicate sources.list as individual sources.list.d .list files?

Tags: software-sources

I'm using puppet's apt module, & I'd like to clear out `sources.list` & have the same structure as individual `sources.list.d` `.list` files.  I've tried several variations on the formatting of the files without success.

I initially just tried copying the `sources.list` entries into individual files, but `apt-get update` complained about being unable to retrieve headers due to inability to find a certain entry.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, and if so, can someone point me at the formatting documentation?

Comment: I believe apt requires sources.list...

Comment: I've made some progress.  Apparently apt doesn't require sources.list, because the first thing that the module does is replace its contents with "content managed by puppet."  Here is my sources.list.d/ubuntu_stable.list file content:

`code`# ubuntu_stable
deb http://my.mirror.org:80/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted multiverse universe
`code`

The problem so far is that apt-get update doesn't include the security or updates aspects of the mirror.  I tried adding updates & security to the end of the line, but that didn't work.